# Increasing the size of the image from Google Callback API

Tags: javascript

I am getting a response from Google which looks something like this

```
{ id: '1027750732631695',
  displayName: 'Rohit Bhatia',
  name: { familyName: 'Bhatia', givenName: 'Rohit' },
  photos: 
   [ { value: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7HxFRQOCd9Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAU8/pgzBQd9X6pA/photo.jpg?sz=50' } ],
  gender: 'male',
  provider: 'google',
  _raw: '{\n "kind": "plus#person",\n "etag": "\\"jb1Xzanox6i8Zyse4Dc\sZqy0/OGJ25piXcT00US9SPJIJuIqzE\\"",\n "gender": "male",\n "objectType": "person",\n "id": "102775073203963169965",\n "displayName": "Rohit Bhatia",\n "name": {\n  "familyName": "Bhatia",\n  "givenName": "Rohit"\n },\n "url": "https://plus.google.com/102775073203963169965",\n "image": {\n  "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7HxF9Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAU8/pgzBQd9X6pA/photo.jpg?sz=50",\n  "isDefault": false\n },\n "isPlusUser": true,\n "language": "en",\n "circledByCount": 8,\n "verified": false\n}\n',
  _json: 
   { kind: 'plus#person',
     etag: '"jb1Xzox6i8Zyse4DcYD8sZqy0/OGJ25piXcT00US9SyJuIqzE"',
     gender: 'male',
     objectType: 'person',
     id: '102775073203916995',
     displayName: 'Rohit Bhatia',
     name: { familyName: 'Bhatia', givenName: 'Rohit' },
     url: 'https://plus.google.com/102775073203963169965',
     image: 
      { url: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7HxFRQOCd9Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAU8/pgzBQd9X6pA/photo.jpg?sz=50',
        isDefault: false },
     isPlusUser: true,
     language: 'en',
     circledByCount: 8,
     verified: false } }
```

Here size of the image is 50 now, 50 Happens to be too small for me so I want the image size to be slightly bigger

```
[ { value: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7HxFRQOCd9Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAU8/pgzBQd9X6pA/photo.jpg?sz=50
```

One way we can do that is by changing value above from 50 to say 250

**So In order to do have a bigger Image, How can I change sz=50 to sz=250 since I am getting the uRL dynamically? I am using Javascript**

Also if in case there is a better method, I am using google-auth-20 in NodeJS for login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change url by substring last 2 chars then add '250' like this :

```
var originalUrl = _json.image.url;
var newUrl = originalUrl.substr(0, originalUrl.length-2);
    newUrl += '250';
```

let's try it :

```js
var oldUrl ="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7HxFRQOCd9Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAU8/pgzBQd9X6pA/photo.jpg?sz=50"

var newUrl = oldUrl.substr(0, oldUrl.length-2);
newUrl += '250';

console.log(newUrl);
```